# monitor going black with vga to hdmi hook-up

Tags: vga

I use my Samsung TV as my computer monitor and to do this I had to get a VGA to HDMI adapter.

It all works fine except when I'm watching something on the computer (my computer is essentially idle so no keystrokes) the screen goes blank for a second with the box telling me "hdmi2 1024x768, etc.

Once it starts doing this, it happens again and again.

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Re-plug your HDMI and VGA inputs. Make sure they are securely plugged in and use the twisties on the VGA to keep the connection secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your `Power Settings` from the `Control Panel` and set the display to Never turn off. Not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Tried it. Didn't work. It just kept blinking on and off, even throughout the restarting process. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you know what Graphics Card your PC is running?

Comment: I'm thinking it's not the idlling thing, "cause now it just keeps doing it even though I'm doing stuff (I'm posting this from my laptop). I tried Samsung and they were no help.

Comment: No. How do I find out?

Comment: Install and run this: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

Comment: You could also go into Device Manager from the Control Panel and expand the Display Adapter node. That'll be easier.

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't figure out how to expand the display adapter node. I found Device Manager and clicked on the device -- it said it's working fine -- I checked for software updates and it said I'm up to date. I might try the software you suggested, and then call a techie if it doesn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: The software I suggested is mainly for monitoring temperatures. It shows other information as well, but it isn't designed to actively detect/fix hardware problems.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled video drivers with vga to hd adapter hooked up rather than installing on vga connection and then switching to adapter. Seems to be working.